Different reflections in viewport and rendering
I have an issue with reflection on the surface of 2 different object:

This render is in viewport and here I have correct reflection (world light reflected on two object).

In this case (final render) I have two reflections on each object instead and I don't know why I have two different results.
Thanks to all in advance!

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
